# Accessing a TEMP TABLE in a TRIGGER on a VIEW

Tags: sqlite

I need to parameterize a view, and I am doing so by creating a `TEMP TABLE` which has the parameters for the view.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE parms (parm1 INTEGER, parm2 INTEGER);
CREATE VIEW tableview AS ...
```

The `VIEW` is rather complex, but it basically uses these two parameters to kick start a recursive CTE, and there isn't any other way that I have found to express the view without these parameters.

The parameters must be stored in a temporary table because each connection should be able to have its own view with different parameters.

In any case, this works fine for creating the view itself, so long as I create the same `TEMP TABLE` at the start of any queries that use the view, e.g.:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE parms (parm1 INTEGER, parm2 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO parms (parm1,parm2) VALUES (5,66);
SELECT * FROM tableview;
```

I am able to do the same thing to create a trigger to allow inserts on the view:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE parms (parm1 INTEGER, parm2 INTEGER);
CREATE TRIGGER tableinsert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON tableview ...
```

However, when I try to do an actual `INSERT` (re-creating the `TEMP TABLE` first as before) I get an error:

```
no such table: main.parms
```

If I create a non-temporary table, I do not get this error, but then I have the problem that different connections can't have their own separate views.

I have review the [documentation for triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger), and it mentions caveats of using temporary triggers on a non-temporary table, but I don't see anything regarding the reverse.

I did find a reference elsewhere that indicated that "the table... must exist in the same database as the table or view to which the trigger is attached".  I thought a temporary table was part of the current database, is this not true?  Is there some way to make this true?

I also tried accessing the `parms` table as `temp.parms` in the TRIGGER, but got the error:

```
qualified table names are not allowed on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE
statements within triggers
```

If I can't use a temporary table, is there some way to work around it to accomplish the same thing?

Update: Ok, so it seems to be an SQLite limitation.  After digging around a bit in the SQLite source code, it seems to be pretty trivial to allow `SELECT` access to a temporary table in a trigger.  However, allowing `UPDATE` access appears to be a lot harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary objects are created in a separate database named `temp`, so they are not accessible from triggers in other databases.

The remaining mechanism to get a connection-specific value into a trigger is to use a user-defined function.